# append string json before end of file json using fopen mode "a" in aws s3

Tags: php, json, amazon-s3

I have a json string at http://mokotest.s3.amazonaws.com/simple.json

The json format is like this :

```
{"simple": [{"name": "ucup"}]}
```

I have another json string in my local computer

```
{"name": "otong"}
```

i want to append the local json string to the remote one in amazonaws using fopen mode "a" and I expect the result to be like this:

```
{"simple": [{"name": "ucup"}, {"name": "otong"}]}
```

This is my php code:

```
$stream = fopen("s3://mokotest/simple.json", 'a', false,
            stream_context_create(array(
            's3' => array(
                    'ACL' => 'public-read',         
                )
            )));

fseek($stream, -3, SEEK_END);
fwrite($stream,  '{"name": "otong"}]}');
fclose($stream);
```

The problem is that the function `fseek` is not working when I append before the end of file using mode "a".

I'm using mode "a" because aws s3 support only  "w", "x", or "a".

Can anyone help me?

*note :
I want to request only once, not issue multiple requests, read first with `fopen` mode "r" and then write with `fopen` mode "w"

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not read and decode, modify, re-encode, and then write a new object.  Even if the S3 library actually supports opening for append, S3 itself has no such operation... objects in S3 can *only* be replaced/overwritten.  They cannot actually be appended to or modified.  Anything that appears to provide this operation must be emulating it with a fetch, modify, and replace.

Comment: hmm, yeaah it can not be.. :(
all right, thanks your answer..
i will read first the json, .. manipulating and then write to overwritten the json ..